# Assigning the instant values of For loop to mutablearray

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, for-loop

I have java code which looks something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<codeWord.length;i++) {
  codeWord[i] = cw_bArray;
}
```

here the codeword is NSDATA & cw_barray is NSMutableArray and in **Objective c** i am doing

```
for(int i=0;i<codeword.length;i++) {
  [codeword objectAtIndex:i] =[cw_bArray mutableCopy];
}
```

but it is popping a error like this
 **Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an objective-c message not allowed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Praven S solution works fine if you are looking for adding object to your array. 
The java code seems more like a replacing object in the array by new ones. In order to achieve that you should use:
    [codeword replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[cw_bArray mutableCopy]];

Like he said, `objectAtIndex` is a getter method. Hence you cannot assign a value to the method result. It would have no sense. Basically what you wrote is give me the i object of the array but you know what? Let say this object is another one.

Comment: how to write switch condition for this `for(int i=0;i<codeWord.length;i++){
    switch (codeWord[i]) `but if the give same in objective c it is popping error **Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector** where codeword is NSData

Comment: Instead of `codeWord[i]` you have to use `[codeWord objectAtIndex:i]` to access the element at index i.
You also could use:
    `for(ElementType element in codeWord)
    {
        switch (element) 
        ...
    }`
  The thing is, in Objective C you cannot use switch on other expression than resulting a number. Hence you cannot perform the switch directly on the element if it is not a number

Answer (score 1):

```
[codeword insertObject:[cw_bArray mutableCopy] atIndex:i];
```

should do the trick for you.

Basically `objectAtIndex` returns a read only copy which cannot be assigned to another object. What you need to do is replace the entire object at that index with your new object.

Comment: how to write swtich condition for this i am trying to this switch (codeword.length[i] ) but in java they have mentioned switch(codeWord[i]) so confused

Comment: I dont know if i understood your comment and question correctly. but i guess this is what you want. [codeword objectAtIndex:i].count